# code hunt game 01.14

Tags: java, algorithm, operators

I am currently playing a game that input a parameter 'x'. I should return expected result.

```
public class Program {
    public static int Puzzle(int x) {
        // RETURN EXPECTED RESULT
        // Hint : You will have to use the modulo % operator to solve this one.
    }
}
```

```
x    EXPECTED RESULT
--   ---------------
1    0
3    1
4    2
5    0
6    4
7    3
8    2
9    1
10   0
23   10
35   10
96   10
```

Any help?

Comment: Do you understand what the modulo operator does ?

Comment: yes. I think the function like **f(x) % 5**

Comment: ... What's `f(2)` supposed to be?  I think somebody's having you on - before `5` the results are _increasing_, but afterwards it's decreasing (in, yes, a simple `f(x) -> x % 5`).  And what's up with the repeated `10`s?

Answer (score 7):

```
public class Program {
    public static int Puzzle(int x) {
        return 10 % x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:
return 10 % x;

Maybe someone else will be able to explain you why this is in math terms. That, I cannot say for sure.